# how to refresh page when new data is inserted into MySql table

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to refresh the div whenever some data is added into the MySQL table
Please help! :D

Comment: You need to expand a bit more on your question.  Who's initiating the request to insert data?

Comment: its actually a social network website that im workin on so i need to refresh the page whenever someone make a new post.
**PLEASE IM A BEGINNER TO PHP AND JQUERY**

Comment: Relax.  @marto's posted answer is what you'll need to look into then.

Comment: which one of them should be good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Jquery [.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/),[.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), or [.getjson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getjson/) (There is also [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

You can do this a couple of ways but here is 1 pretty simple way.

**MYSQL:**
If you do not have a filed for last update, add one. This will allow you to check when the the table was last updated.

**PHP:**
Grab the last update date from the MYSQL table and compare it to the last "last update date" that you got the last time the ajax call was run. If you ran the last ajax call 5 minutes ago and the table was updated 4 minutes ago, then output a 1, otherwise output a 0.

**Jquery:**

```
$.get('checkupdate.php?lastupdate='+$("#lastUpdate").val(),function(data){
   if(data == '1'){
    refreshData();
   }
 });
```

This is assuming that when you get your data, you toss the lastUpdateDate into a hidden field or you could even assign it to a global variable...

I hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to periodically check for new content and load the results into the div.

Comment: The jQuery documentaiton has working examples. Pay attention to callbacks: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: so which one do you suggest me to use out of them

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `which one`? The page I linked to is the jQuery documentation. I'm suggesting you learn how to use this and implment a solution using it, not that there is an example on the page which you can simply copy and paste into your application which will somehow magically work with your HTML and serverside code.